# Sort chart legend in PowerView

Tags: sql-server-2012, powerpivot, dax, powerview

I'm playing about with PowerView at the moment and have run into a slight issue. I've got a line chart (below) but would really like to sort the legend (Keyword) depending on the latest value of the data point in the chart (currently sorts alphabetically).

Is this possible either a) within PowerView itself or b) by adding some sort of calculated column to the series table via DAX and defining that as the sort column in the underlying PowerPivot model?

[image: sample PowerView line chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the underlying Tabular model or PowerPivot workbook sourcing data into the Power View slate, change the sorting of the Keyword with another column representing your required condition. With 2012, you have the capability of sorting columns by other columns within the model/workbook.